# Using htaccess to redirect anything after a parameter - regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Id like to have the following URL(s) redirect to the same URL just without the ?

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/this-is-static?numbersletterssymbols
```

goes to

```
https://www.example.com/this-is-static
```

"numbersletterssymbols" can be anything

Id like this to be a 301 , using htaccess ( apache )

I came across the following, however, the variable seems to be in parentheses

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^test.php$ %1/? [R=301,L]
```

Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the query string (*any* query string) from *any* URL you could do the following using mod_rewrite, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) simply asserts that there is a query string consisting of at least 1 character (determined by the regex `.` - a single dot).

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the original query string from the redirected response. The `QSD` flag requires Apache 2.4 (which you are most probably using). The method used on earlier versions of Apache, as in your example, is to append a `?` to the *susbstitution* string (essentially an *empty* query string).

Note that you should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

> however, the variable seems to be in parentheses

The parentheses in the regex simply creates a "capturing group" which can be referenced later with a backreference. eg. In your example, the value of the `product` URL parameter is referenced in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string using the `%1` backreference in order to *redirect* to the value of the URL parameter. This is very different to what you are trying to do and is arguably a security issue. eg. It would redirect a request for `/test.php?product=https://malicious.com` to `https://malicious.com/`, allowing a potential hacker to relay traffic via your site.

---

> **UPDATE:** is it possible to make this work only for when the URL begins with "this-is-static" (for example)

Yes, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) matches the URL-path, less the slash prefix. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^this-is-static %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Matches all URLs that *start with* `/this-is-static`.